# Regex c# - where to insert the blank space

Tags: c#, regex

I want to allow the user to enter the year in blank but I don´t know where to put \s\s\s\s in the following expression.
Here is an example of what I need to do: if the user inserts 03-07-_____ the program must be executed every 3Th of July of each year(and it proceeds the same way if the user inserts blank date, month or year or twoo of this three)

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rdate =
    new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^((((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]|\s\s|\s\d)[\-](0?[13578]|1[02]|\s\s)[\-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\-](0?[13456789]|1[012])[\-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\-]0?2[\-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(29[\-]0?2[\-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00)))|(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[13578]|1[02])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(0[13456789]|1[012])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])02((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(2902((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00))))$");
```

Could someone help me?(this expression validates even a leap year)

Comment: This looks like it's also dealing with days in addition to years, is that correct?  Or are you dealing with a field that only contains year?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a "write-only" regex.

Comment: Please post the string that you want to match with the updated regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what You asked for

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rdate =
    new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^((((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]|\s\s|\s\d)[\-](0?[13578]|1[02]|\s\s)[\-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}|\s\s\s\s))|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\-](0?[13456789]|1[012])[\-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}|\s\s\s\s))|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\-]0?2[\-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}|\s\s\s\s))|(29[\-]0?2[\-]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00|\s\s\s\s)))|(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[13578]|1[02])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(0[13456789]|1[012])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])02((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(2902((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00))))$");
```

But I am not sure it is what You really want. The regex was already patched, I continued the way. But not only it is maintenance nightmare, it behaves strange. It accepts empty day, but only when month is january, march, may... or empty. Less lines of code is not always better. I would suggest to rewrite it completely. Something simmilar to this:

```
    protected DateTime? getDateTimeFromParts(string day, string month, string year)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        int iyear;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(year))
        {
            iyear = now.Year;
        }
        else
        {
            iyear = int.Parse(year);
            if (iyear >= 0 && iyear < 100) { iyear += 2000; }
        }

        int imonth;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(month))
        {
            imonth = now.Month;
        }
        else
        {
            imonth = int.Parse(month);
        }

        int iday;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(day))
        {
            iday = now.Day;
        }
        else
        {
            iday = int.Parse(day);
        }

        if (iyear <= DateTime.MaxValue.Year && iyear >= DateTime.MinValue.Year)
        {
            if (imonth >= 1 && imonth <= 12)
            {
                if (DateTime.DaysInMonth(iyear, imonth) >= iday && iday >= 1)
                    return new DateTime(iyear, imonth, iday);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected DateTime? getDateTime(string dateStr)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"^(\d\d)(\d\d)((\d\d)?\d\d)$");
        Match m = r.Match(dateStr);

        if (m.Success)
        {
            return getDateTimeFromParts(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value);
        }

        r = new Regex(@"^(\d?\d|\s\d|\s\s)[-](\d?\d|\s\s)[-]((\d\d)?\d\d|\s\s\s\s)$");
        m = r.Match(dateStr);

        if (m.Success)
        {
            return getDateTimeFromParts(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value);
        }

        return null;
    }
```